# How to add FreeGLUT and GLEW to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, opengl, glew, freeglut

I'm totally new to OpenGL and trying to set it up on Xcode. I want to install FreeGLUT and GLEW but I'm totally confused with the different steps that are mentioned on different websites. What are the specific steps to add FreeGLUT and GLEW? and what are the reasons for doing these steps?